# in Sinatra how do you make a "before" filter that matches all routes except some

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Ruby Sinatra app and I have some code which I need to execute on all routes except for a few exceptions. How do I do this?

If I wanted to execute the code on selected routes (whitelist style) I'd do this:

```
['/join', "/join/*", "/payment/*"].each do |path|
    before path do
        #some code
    end
end
```

How do I do it the other way round though (blacklist style)? I want to match all routes except `'/join'`, `'/join/*'` and `'/payment/*'`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With negative look-ahead:

```
before /^(?!\/(join|payment))/ do
  # ...
end
```

With `pass`:

```
 before do
   pass if %w[join payment].include? request.path_info.split('/')[1]
   # ...
 end
```

Or you could create a [custom matcher](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Custom%20Route%20Matchers).

Comment: how can I include the root path ('/') in this pass statement?

Comment: pass if ['join', 'payment', nil].include? request.path_info.split('/')[1]

Comment: The pass works well for me but the negative look-ahead does not. Two problems: 1) Sinatra (1.4.6 at least) has a parsing error with a ^ character in a regular expression and 2) the negative look-ahead syntax only checks for the escaped forward-slash. Variable-width values aren't allowed. https://rubular.com/r/HEWorY6OFU5W9S

Answer (score 4):

What I did to make a "before all, except..." filter is use a splat, and then run code on splat conditions.

```
before '/*' do
  unless params[:splat] == 'nofilter' || params[:splat] == 'beta'
    redirect '/beta'
  end
end
```

This allowed me to make a before filter with a redirect that didn't create a redirect loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions for routing in sinatra

for example:

```
get %r{/hello/([\w]+)} do |c|
   "Hello, #{c}!"
end
```

taken from [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes). there you can find further informations.

to build and test your regex you can use http://rubular.com/

Comment: See, that's already clear from reading the docs. What's not clear from the docs (Sinatra: README) is whether or not *before filters* can also take regex patterns. You'll notice how *before and after filters* are in an entirely different section of the article to which you linked. So your answer adds no value (except perhaps that last link) and merely repeats what the docs already state. Thus my downvote.